# Notepad++ : how to reattach the "find result" box?

Tags: notepad++

I accidentally detached the search result box and it's now an independant window. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### Method1:

Double click the title bar of the separated result box. It should return to its default docked position. (you have to double click where the red cross on the screenshot is)

[image]

### Method2:

Drag it by by the title bar down towards the lower border of the window as shown on this screenshot:

[image]

Until the border showing the default position of the results box appears as shown on this screenshot:

[image]

You have to drag so that your mouse cursor is precizely on the edge of the status bar of NP++ main window

Release the mouse button... Done!

Comment: I guess method one is easier to use

Comment: Dragging works really badly. Notepad++ becomes barely responsive when "Find" window is moved, etc.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty sluggish - reminds me of trying to remove an unresponsive window in Windows 3.1 - once it is docked, it's fine.  But damn, there should be a button or something.

Comment: In my case Method 1's result is NOT the one expected. Method 2 works fine.Versailles, Wed 05 May 2021 20:49:20 +0200

Answer (score 8):

Just drag the search results window to the bottom (onto the status bar) of the Notepad++ main window and there should appear a gray line. If you release the mouse button, the search results windows should dock again.

Comment: Just to add, align the top edge(aligning bottom edge doesn't dock)of the find windowalong the bottom status bar.